# How to prove convexity of $S=\{ (x_{1},x_{2}):x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2\leq1 \}$

Tags: convex-analysis

$$S_{1}=\{ (x_{1},x_{2}):x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2\leq 1 \}$$

I cant solve trying with an alpha value $\in[0,1]$ by two dummy vectors. Please can anyone tell me how to prove it is not convex set ?

what I tried is

Defined two vectors
$$a=(a_{1},a_{2})\in S_{1}$$ so $$a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2\leq 1$$,
$$b=(b_{1},b_{2})\in S_{1}$$ so $$b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2\leq1$$,

and tried to prove
$$\alpha\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\a_{2}
\end{bmatrix}+(1-\alpha)\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\in S_{1} ? ?$$

it was so hard to me continuing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\overline{x},\overline{y}\in S$. We'll show that for any $\lambda\in[0,1]$, the vector $\lambda\overline{x}+(1-\lambda)\overline{y}\in S$. That is to say we need to show that $|\lambda\overline{x}+(1-\lambda)\overline{y}|\leq 1$. This follows more or less immediatley from the triangle inequality:

\begin{align*}
|\lambda\overline{x} + (1-\lambda)\overline{y}| &\leq |\lambda\overline{x}| + |(1-\lambda)\overline{y}|\\
& = |\lambda||\overline{x}| + |1-\lambda||\overline{y}|\\
& \leq |\lambda| + |1-\lambda|\\
& = 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for solution, where did $\overline{x}$ and  $\overline{y}$ go at the 3rd step ? I don't understand

Comment: That is where we use the assumption that $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ belong to $S$. By definition, they have norm less than or equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Just one more question; does "equals 1" mean that it is impossible to be greater than 1 ? How can I be sure ?

Comment: We proved the desired inequality by looking at a string of inequalities. Some of these happen to be on-the-nose equalities, but that doesn't really matter. Since "less than or equal to" is a transitive property, we proved that $|\lambda\overline{x} + (1-\lambda)\overline{y}|\leq 1$. This means, by definition of "less than or equal to", that this quantity is no greater than 1.

Comment: It should be noted that the norm squared does not satisfy the triangle inequality, and this proof is true because $a_1^2+a_2^2\leq 1 \Rightarrow \|(a_1,a_2)\|=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}\leq \sqrt{1}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The Hessian of the function $\left(x_1,x_2\right) \mapsto x^2_1 + x^2_2$ is $2I$, so this function is convex. Any set of the form $g\left(x\right) \leq c$ where $g$ is a convex function is a convex set.